# Properties of eigenvectors of a sample covariance matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, statistics, signal-processing

My apology if the question is not appropriate. For me Eigenvectors are quite a mystery. Does it have any property that we can relate to the matrix it came from? By property I mean something like the sum of its elements, relation between real and imaginary part of the element, etc.

My specific interest is: consider a sample covariance matrix $A$ which is positive definite Hermitian matrix. Further,the sample covariance matrix is of size $N$ by $N$ and derived from an $N$ sensor system receiving band limited-signal over time.

Are there any specific properties of the eigenvectors of $A$? If there are any, how we can even formulate the problem? That Eigenvalues are variances and Eigenvectors are corresponding directions is a known property, but is there anything else?

Comment: If you truly mean that eigenvectors are a mystery for you, perhaps you should look into the basic definition of an eigenvector and puzzle on some basic examples. Once you "get there", you can ponder about those other questions you have posed. Nothing inappropriate with your question, but first things first I would recommend

Comment: Are you sure it is not mystery as no one has mentioned any properties yet??

Comment: That's because you can find them in any linear algebra textbook. Get a copy from amazon or so. Take an older edition so that it won't hurt your wallet.

Comment: I am really sorry as this question is not understood. If such a functional exist then we could have got the Eigenvectors without computing them is not it?